# Web.Config Issues

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web application that has a web.config file in the website's parent directory. I have another folder in the website which has another asp.net application. The folder also has a web.config directory for itself. When I run the application within the sub folder, it throws error and somehow these errors are related to references in root level application.

Initially it threw this error: code sub directory doesnt exist, . I added a dummy folder for this within the application in the sub folder but it seems to be looking for more references. is there a way to resolve this issue.

Parent application has it's own config and the application within Sub folder has it's own web.config. Whe i run the appl within sub folder, it is trying to use the web.config from parent application not it's own.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Can you give specific error messages?  Without that, we can give you general things to look for, but we can give better help with more info.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'PrintTask_VBNet, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a7e7966c16048d7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PrintTask_VBNet, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a7e7966c16048d7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

you must clarify this:

> I have an ASP.NET web application that has a web.config file in the
>   website's parent directory. I have another folder in the website which
>   has another asp.net application. The folder also has a web.config
>   directory for itself.

1. are you telling us you installed a web app and its web.config is not in the same folder but in a parent folder? This is wrong!
2. your other folder contains an asp.net application which has a web.config directory!?!?

in ASP.NET for nested or not nested applications you should basically have the web.config in the same folder where you have the default.aspx page and the bin sub-folder, if the web.config is not there but in any parent or child folder, it won't work, most likely.

I am assuming things here as you do not explain much, edit the question with more details and I will edit this answer :)